# Android: Can I create an activity conditionally?

Tags: android, android-activity

For eg: I am using one Activity for Different UI pages with different he. So I want to check if an activity with a particular parameter in the intent exists. If it does just bring it to the top or else create another instance of an activity.

I have tried adding the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to the intent but that does not solve my purpose.Here is some code: I want to create an activity only if there is a new title.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DISPLAY_NAME, title);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'header name'?

Comment: Why don't you just update the current activity content?
Remember that mobile app should be light, so it's not a good idea to store too much (or not currently necessary) data in the memory.

Comment: I am building a Messenger App. So Every Group in the chat would be an instance of GroupActivity with a different GroupHeader.